# Exported firebase cloud firestore data to cloud storage, data is encrypted how to use now?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I exported my cloud Firestore database to a cloud storage but, I can’t verify it will be able to use as a backup since data looks encrypted. My question is, will I be able to decrypt somehow or am only limited to GCP processes to decrypt the data in case I need it as a back up

Answer (score 3):

The data is not encrypted, it's just serialized in a special format.  You can take those exports, copy them around, and re-import them from a different bucket to a different database.  You will have to use one of the documented methods [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) or [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export), else figure out how to parse the data yourself (which is not documented, but they are probably protobufs).